# Segmentation fault when using gdb-multiarch with Eclipse for remote debugging on ARM system

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging

I am trying to use gdb-multiarch to remotely debug C++ code on an ARM system. When I use gdb-multiarch in the terminal, everything works fine. However, when I try to do the same thing using Eclipse, I encounter a segmentation fault.

Here is the output I get when I use gdb-multiarch in the terminal:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
...
(gdb) set architecture arm
The target architecture is set to "arm".
(gdb) target remote 10.XX.XX.51:12345
Remote debugging using 10.XX.XX.51:12345
...
0xb6f89980 in _start () from target:/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
...
[Inferior 1 (process 517) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

However, when I use Eclipse, I get the following output:

```
New UI allocated
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
...
(gdb) 0xb6f36980 in _start () from target:/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000 in ?? ()

(gdb) 
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb)
```

I have the following output when compiling:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/Main.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/home/dbo/workspace_1/dbus_automatictestinterface/DBus_AutomaticTestInterface/Debug/../ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -g -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Main.d" -MT"src/Main.o" -o "src/Main.o" "../src/Main.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/Main.cpp
 
Building target: DBus_AutomaticTestInterface
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-g++  -o "DBus_AutomaticTestInterface" ./src/Main.o   
Finished building target: DBus_AutomaticTestInterface
```

In Eclipse, I have the following settings under Run -> Debug Configurations... -> GDB Hardware Debugging:

- Project: DBus_AutomaticTestInterface
- C/C++ Application: /home/dbo/workspace_1/dbus_automatictestinterface/DBus_AutomaticTestInterface/Debug/DBus_AutomaticTestInterface
- Build Configuration: Use Active
- GDB Command: gdb-multiarch
- Debug server: Generic TCP/IP
- Protocol: remote
- Connection: 10:XX:XX.51:12345

On the ARM system, gdbserver is started with the following command:
`gdbserver :12345 DBus_AutomaticTestInterface`

Why am I encountering a segmentation fault when using Eclipse, and how can I resolve this issue?

I have attempted several troubleshooting steps to resolve this issue. I have restarted SSH on the system multiple times, as well as rebooted the entire system. I have recompiled the project multiple times and tried various flags. I have updated Eclipse and the associated extensions. I have also checked the dependencies and ensured there are no unused shared libraries.